# Is there any connection between Lakshmi-Narsimha and Sri Chakra?

Tags: gods, lakshmi, narasimha, sri-vidya

Is there any link between Lakshmi-Narsimha and Sri Chakra (Lalita Devi? Is there any relevant text or story that expands or clarifies this point?

What made me think of this were [these lines from this blog](http://shanmatha.blogspot.in/2009/09/connection-of-sastha-with-srividya.html?m=1):

> Devi has four powerful deities guarding her kingdom. The two are the powerful deities Ashtamukha Gandabherunda Nrisimha and Sashaktika Maha Vamana. The third is Kalasamkarshini Kali and fourth is our Master - Lord Shasta accompanied by Purna and Pushkala.

Comment: No there is no connection. But what made u think that there is?

Comment: Thanks rickross, good that u asked that. Have updated my que with the details that made me think.

Comment: I know the various Kramas of Sri Vidya. You can get them in Nityotsava too. There is no such connection.

Comment: Narasimha is linked to Sudarshana Chakra not with Sri Chakra.